# resetting permalinks after changing page names

Tags: plugins, permalinks

After a lengthy staging time, many page categories, pages within pages, need to be retitled. This made a mess of my link structure and now I'm having a real hard time try to figure out how to reset all of the different links.

If you had made a page, then created 15 pages within that page as a structure, then another 15 pages in each of those pages, then retitled the first page – how do you edit the link structure?

I'm stumped.

Comment: Essentially "How do I change a pages slug?"

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% what you mean. Apologies if this is obvious but... if just want to change the parent page title, and have that reflected in all the link structures you'd change the permalink for the page, just underneath the page title. Or is it something different?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot would improve this answer and make it clearer

Comment: in the example above, what I need to be able to alter is the (WP-tests – 20 –) section. I have a ton of pages that exist within that red box.  is that clear?

Comment: if you have /a/b /a/c and /a/d, and I change a's slug to q, all the rest will change too